# swapping characters in 3rd column using sed/awk

Tags: sed, awk, swap

A files has 3 columns:

123711184642,3583090366663629,0036f920012437d4
123715942138,3538710295145500,0136f920afd6c643

I want to delete the first two characters in the third column:
123711184642,3583090366663629,36f920012437d4
123715942138,3538710295145500,36f920afd6c643

And swap the first 6 characters, in twos,  of the third column such that the final result is:
123711184642,3583090366663629,639f02012437d4
123715942138,3538710295145500,639f02afd6c643

Any assistance will be appreciated.
Bernie

Comment: Am I tripping or is there only two columns in the sample data?

Comment: There are 3 columns separated by comma ",".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input data is in the file "foo", you could do:

```
cat foo | awk -F "," -f awkfile
```

where awkfile would contain:

```
{
  v = ""
  p = $3
  printf ("%s,%s,", $1, $2)
  for (i=3; i<9; i=i+2) {
     printf ("%s%s", substr(p, i+1, 1), substr (p, i, 1))
  }
  printf ("%s\n", substr(p, 9))
}
```

Comment: Hi Kelly.Something's not right here:0136f920afd6c643 has 16 digits.After running the awk script, it becomes 639f02fafd6c643.This has 15 digits not 14 digits. Also notice there's an extra "f".There are only two "fs" in the original.

Comment: Sorry, the last substr(p, 10) should have been substr(p, 9) and the prior loop should have been corrected to be < 9. I have edited my answer and verified it matches the target result you posted.  Again, sorry about that -- I should have double checked in the first place.

Comment: It's not necessary to use `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

With sed it's just a matter of grouping:

```
sed '
    s/\(.*,\)../\1/;
    s/,\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\([^,]*\)$/,\2\1\4\3\6\5\7/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With gawk:

```
gawk -F, '
    BEGIN {OFS=FS}
    { 
        $3 = gensub(/^..(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.*)/, "\\2\\1\\4\\3\\6\\5\\7", 1, $3)
        print
    }
' in.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` 1-liner. Doesn't care how many fields you have as long as you just want to alter the last. It also doesn't care how many pairs the last field has, it will swap them just the same.

<del>sed 'h;s/^.*,..//;s/(.)(.)/\2\1/g;x;s/,[^,]*$/,/;G;s/\n//' /path/to/file</del>

#### Input

```
$ cat ./infile
123711184642,3583090366663629,0036f920012437d4
123715942138,3538710295145500,0136f920afd6c643
```

#### Output

```
$ sed 'h;s/^.*,..//;s/\(.\)\(.\)/\2\1/g;x;s/,[^,]*$/,/;G;s/\n//' ./infile
123711184642,3583090366663629,639f021042734d
123715942138,3538710295145500,639f02fa6d6c34
```

#### Explanation

1. `h` -- make a copy of the entire
2. `s/^.*,..//` -- Pattern space now
   holds only the last field with its
   two leading numbers removed
3. `s/\(.\)\(.\)/\2\1/g` -- Do the number
   swap in pairs on the pattern space
4. `x` -- swap pattern space with hold
   space
5. `s/,[^,]*$/,/` -- Remove the entire
   last field
6. `G` -- Append the hold space to the
   pattern space with an '\n' between
   them
7. `s/\n//` -- Remove the '\n' added by
   `G`

Comment: The output doesn't match the requested output.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` 1-liner just for the fun of it.  This doesn't care how many pairs of numbers are in the 3rd field, it will work on all of them.

<del>awk -F, '{$3=substr(gensub(/(.)(.)/,"\2\1","g",$3),3)}1' OFS=, /path/to/file</del>

#### Input

```
$ cat ./infile
123711184642,3583090366663629,0036f920012437d4
123715942138,3538710295145500,0136f920afd6c643
```

#### Output

```
$ awk -F, '{$3=substr(gensub(/(.)(.)/,"\\2\\1","g",$3),3)}1' OFS=, ./infile
123711184642,3583090366663629,639f021042734d
123715942138,3538710295145500,639f02fa6d6c34
```

Comment: The output doesn't match the requested output.